# c++ using scope resolution operator in function call parameter

Tags: c++, qt

Can someone please point me to an explanation what e.g. `QIODevice::WriteOnly` actually does?

full line of code:

```
file.open(stderr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
```

from that [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html) for the QIODevice class, WriteOnly is as enum constant with value 2. It indicates that the device is open for writing.

I believe that the following example for `enum hack` will be useful to you.

```
class MyClass1 {
public:
    enum { SIZE=10 };
};

class MyClass2 {
public:
    enum { SIZE=20 };
};

int main() {
    cout << MyClass1::SIZE << "\t" << MyClass2::SIZE << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`QIODevice::WriteOnly` is just a flag, you're saying that you want to open the file *only for writing*.

If you would want only to read the file, `QIODevice::ReadOnly` would be the necessary flag to use.

And to read and write use flag: `QIODevice::ReadWrite`:

```
file.open(stderr, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```